# Why is my icloud backup taking so long?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

I just created an icloud account and i am backing it up and it says it will take 3 hours.  I have no pictures on my phone so i think its just backing up contacts, reminders, etc.  Does anyone know why it would take this long?  Is there something that i could be configured incorrectly?  Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iCloud backups the following:

- Photos and videos in the Camera Roll
- Device settings (for example: Phone Favorites, Wallpaper, and Mail, Contacts, Calendar accounts)
- App data
- Home screen and app organization
- Messages (iMessage, SMS, and MMS)
- Ringtones
- Visual Voicemails

It might be due to your app data size and also if this is the first time backing up then it will take a bit longer. Have a look at this [link](http://techsupport.foreverwarm.com/why-does-it-take-so-long-to-backup-to-icloud), it will explain why else it might  take longer.